# xcode simultor - library not found for

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, cocoapods

I'm trying to run my ios project on the simulator but I'm told that:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-.....
```

This is not happening if I run it on my device.

I tried looking into the search paths in my Pods project, but I didn't see anything suspicious... Maybe i'm not looking for the right thing.

Can anyone help me by telling me what should I look for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

I went to the Pods project file and saw that "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to Yes on debug but set to No on release... I just set it to No on both and it works...

Answer (score 0):

That means that there is no libPods-....dylib in the library search path that you passed to the linker.  I can't be more specific because you omitted the rest of the library name in your question.  You should make sure that your library search paths are correctly pointing to where you have the iOS Simulator version of your library.